# Adaptive Headlight Issue

Tags: toyota, rav4, adaptive-headlight

So I recently had a fender bender in my 2021 RAV4 which resulted in a broken headlight. I got a new headlight and swapped the old module onto it, and since then I’ve been getting this error on startup and the adaptive feature no longer works. The headlights work fine otherwise. I took it to Toyota and they said that it doesn’t need coding or anything like that, and they weren’t able to figure out the issue. Just wondering if anyone out there might have any suggestions? I did re-calibrate the steering angle sensor and checked the level sensor in the back, but couldn’t find any issues. Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!